# JUnit 5: How do I use multiple extensions in a test written in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4, junit5, mockk

I am trying to migrate my tests for a `ViewModel` from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, and use MockK in conjunction. In JUnit4, I have made use of rules--namely rules for RxJava2, LiveData, and Coroutines within one test, and it has worked well. Here's how I use them:

```
class CollectionListViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    @get:Rule
    val taskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val rxSchedulerRule = RxSchedulerRule()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    val coroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    @Mock
    lateinit var getAllCollectionsUseCase: GetAllCollectionsUseCase

    private lateinit var SUT: CollectionListViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        SUT = CollectionListViewModel(getAllCollectionsUseCase)
    }
...
}
```

In trying to migrate to JUnit5, I learned that Rules are now Extensions, and after searching I have pieced together replacements for the previous rules I used, and having replaced Mockito with MockK, I have tried to replace Rules with Extensions in this manner:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Extensions(
    ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class),
    ExtendWith(MainCoroutineExtension::class),
    ExtendWith(RxSchedulerExtension::class)
)
class CollectionListViewModelTest {

    @MockK
    lateinit var getAllCollectionsUseCase: GetAllCollectionsUseCase

    private lateinit var SUT: CollectionListViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        SUT = CollectionListViewModel(getAllCollectionsUseCase)
    }
...
```

However, I am getting an error saying that the `getMainLooper` isn't mocked, which is the same error encountered if not using the InstantTaskExecutorRule in JUnit4:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

What is the proper way of using multiple Extensions in Junit5?

Comment: can you post MainCoroutineExtension or any Extension class

Comment: @YLS See this [link](https://gist.github.com/alvindizon/227735c2e21763368cc248912476cf0f)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `@Extension`, I should have used `@ExtendWith` in this manner:

```
@ExtendWith(value = [InstantExecutorExtension::class, MainCoroutineExtension::class, RxSchedulerExtension::class])
```

Or in an even shorter manner:

```
@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class, MainCoroutineExtension::class, RxSchedulerExtension::class)
```